# Checking username and password in Android using SQLite database

Tags: sqlite

I want to get query from SQLite Database in my APP that consist of name, surname, username and also password.

### when I click login button, it made crash. here is my code ##

```
public String Login(String Username, String Password) {

    String Q = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TBLname + " WHERE "
            + DBHelper.ColumnUser + " = " + Username
            + " AND " + DBHelper.ColumnPass + " = " + Password;

    Cursor LoginQuery = MyDB.rawQuery(Q, null);

    if (LoginQuery == null) {
        LoginQuery.close();
        String LoginResult = "Wrong User Name and Password";
        return LoginResult;
    }
        LoginQuery.moveToFirst();
        String LoginResult = LoginQuery.getString(3);
        LoginQuery.close();
    return LoginResult;
}
```

Comment: show program error log

Comment: it only revert "com.etudedevelopres.etude E/SQLiteLog: (1) "

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this without dbhelper:

```
SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE Username=YOUR_USERNAME AND Password=YOUR_PASSWORD
```

Comment: I disabled LoginQuery.close, but problem still exists

Comment: try this:don't user dbhelper and use predefined names and execute the program maybe problem be your dbhelper.

Comment: by the way ,without error log it's impossible for us to solve the problem.

Comment: Here is my Log: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.etudedevelopres.etude, PID: 3224
                                                                         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AND": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TblUsers WHERE Username =  AND Password =

Comment: E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "AND": syntax error

Comment: your error resource is here:DBHelper.ColumnPass check it

Comment: I found new error: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                           Process: com.etudedevelopres.etude, PID: 29735
                                                                           android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Araz (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM TblUsers WHERE Username = Araz AND Password = 313

Comment: but as I double checked my database, Tblusers in my devise, Username column is exists

Comment: i think your db wouldn't create ur db or your table name is incorrect

Comment: as i told you the problem is your helper

Comment: Mr. AF, problem was solved by changeing the Quer code with below:                    String Q = "SELECT * FROM " + DBHelper.TBLname + " WHERE "
                + DBHelper.ColumnUser + " = '" + Username
                + "' AND " + DBHelper.ColumnPass + " = '" + Password+"'";

Comment: it needs single quotes before/after input Username and password